# cannot find octovis for viewing the built map

Tags: ros, octomap, ros-fuerte, octovis

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ros-fuerte. I used rgbdslam package to built a map. I saved the map as 'name.bt'.
When I am trying to view it using
rosrun octovis octovis <filename.bt>

I got the error octovis stack/package not found.

But I checked the installed location using '$ dpkg -L ros-fuerte-octovis'

I got output as:

/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/ros-fuerte-octovis
/usr/share/doc/ros-fuerte-octovis/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/ros-fuerte-octovis/copyright
/opt
/opt/ros
/opt/ros/fuerte
/opt/ros/fuerte/bin
/opt/ros/fuerte/bin/octovis
/opt/ros/fuerte/include
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/octovis
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/octovis/TrajectoryDrawer.h
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/octovis/ColorOcTreeDrawer.h
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/octovis/SelectionBox.h
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/octovis/OcTreeDrawer.h
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/octovis/OcTreeRecord.h
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/octovis/PointcloudDrawer.h
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/octovis/SceneObject.h
/opt/ros/fuerte/lib
/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/liboctovis.a
/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/cmake
/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/cmake/octovis
/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/cmake/octovis/octovis-config.cmake
/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/cmake/octovis/octovis-config-version.cmake
/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/liboctovis.so

Is there any possible solutions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39349/cannot-find-octovis-for-viewing-the-built-map/) by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 171 on 2012-07-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You no longer start octovis as a ROS package in fuerte (i.e. with "rosrun"). It is now installed as a regular system-wide library, so you start it just like any other program:

```
octovis <filename.bt>
```

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2012-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) on 2012-07-20**:
Initially, I tried that too and also now. But, I got the same error,
ERROR: Filestream to 1stmap.bt not open, nothing read.

**Comment by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) on 2012-07-20**:
Sorry. In the mapping process instead of using openni_node.launch, I used openni.launch from other package. So, I guess the map was not built. But, I cannot find the file openni_node.launch in openni_camera package.

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2012-07-20**:
That is a completely different problem, I guess. What happens if you open octovis (without filename), then go the File / Open and pick your file?

**Comment by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) on 2012-07-20**:
I solved the problem. I cannot find openni_node.launch because its located in the package openni_camera_deprecated. But, in older versions its located in openni_camera. So, try for
$ roslaunch openni_camera_deprecated openni_node.launch